# Run two vlookup if an 'N/A'

Tags: excel

I am currently in the process of trying to create a vlookup function that will check cell A2 and check it on sheet1. If it brings back an error, it should go to B2 and then check on sheet1 and bring back the results.

This is what i currently have:

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A2,'Sheet1'!$A$2:$A$1932,1,FALSE)),"0",VLOOKUP(B2,'Sheet1'!$A$2:$A$1932,1,FALSE))
```

But it doesn't seem to be bringing back all the results, it is bringing back some results from each list A2 and B2.

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you use VLOOKUP with column INDEX of 1 then the result of the VLOOKUP, if it isn't an error, is just the lookup value itself. Don't you want a result from another column? If so which one?

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A2,'Sheet1'!$A$2:$A$1932,1,FALSE)),"0",VLOOKUP(A2,'Sheet1'!$A$2:$B$1932,2,FALSE))
```

Or you can use an `IFERROR` to make things shorter:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,'Sheet1'!$A$2:$B$1932,2,FALSE),"0")
```

(You can omit the quotes around `0` if you mean a numerical `0` as opposed to a text `0`)

This formula will get the value from column B in Sheet1 using the lookup value A2 from Sheet2 and looking it up in column A in Sheet1.

`VLOOKUP` checks the value of `A2` in column `Sheet1!A:A` and returns the value from column `Sheet1!B:B` with the formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,'Sheet1'!$A$2:$B$1932,2,FALSE)
                           ^      ^
                           1      2
```

1. B is the result column
2. 2 is in the index relative to A. A is column 1, B is column 2.

---

EDIT:

If you want to get the value from column A only,  checking the value of A2 first and B2 on failure of the first, then you can use:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,'Sheet1'!$A$2:$A$1932,1,FALSE),VLOOKUP(A2,'Sheet1'!$A$2:$A$1932,1,FALSE))
```

Comment: Aren't there 2 lookup values Jerry? I assume it should be something like this - =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,.....),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,.....),0))

Comment: @barryhoudini I was under the impression OP was looking to get the value from column B... guess I was wrong :(

Comment: @JSG You could have said that this was not what you were looking for and I would have made the necessary changes... Oh well =/

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,'Sheet1'!$A$2:$A$1932,1,FALSE),VLOOKUP(B2,'Sheet1'!$A$2:$A$1932,1,FALSE))
```

It will use A2 to and try and find it in sheet1 and if it returns an error, it will go B2 and find the item on sheet1.

Comment: Another way would be to use COUNTIF like this: =IF(COUNTIF('Sheet1'!$A$2:$A$1932,A2),A2,IF(COUNTIF('Sheet1'!$A$2:$A$1932,B2),B2,0))